# Windows doesn't launch Python 3.7 even it is in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, windows

This is my `PATH` environment variable:

`C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\hugol\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hugol\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\hugol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;`

As you can see, Python directory is in it, but when I type `python` in the command line, windows launches a dialog for installing Python 3.9 instead of launching python shell.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `PYTHONPATH` env variable set? Have you verified that is the correct path to you python install is is there absolutely a file `"C:\Users\hugol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"`?  Do you get the same thing if you try running `py` rather than `python`?

Comment: Use `py`.  It's installed in c:\windows (the 2nd thing in your path) and lets you run multiple versions of Python. See [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10:

1. Go to Start, type: Manage app execution aliases
2. Find the entries of Python App Installers and switch all them off.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

In the end, the only solution that worked was to uninstall Python and installing it again, but this time from the Windows store.

Comment: You gave up?  I'm sure there was a better solution.

Comment: Well, It tried other recommendation and they didn't work, and I had no much time to keep on trying until one of them worked, so y tried this and it worked. Problem solved without any trade-off, and that is the goal, isn't it?